# matrix construction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity, determinant

Given any matrix $A$, can one construct a matrix $B$ such that

1. $B$ is nonnegative and the spectral radius of $B$ is strictly less than 1
2. the determinant of $A$ is equal to the first entry of $B^*$ where $B^*=(I-B)^{-1}$.

Here, by constructing, I certainly do NOT mean "trivial" ones like first computing the determinant of $A$. From the complexity perspective, I want a Logspace algorithm.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the "first entry" of a matrix?

Comment: This would yield an O(log(n)) algorithm for finding the determinant of a square matrix.  Is this possible?

Comment: @ncmathsadist: How so? You'd still need to invert the matrix to get the determinant. (also I don't think maomao is looking for O(log n) *time*) Still, I'm inclined to think that such an algorithm does not exist. maomao, do you know any similar examples? What leads you to suspect there is such an algorithm?

Comment: What does he mean by "logspace"?  The stipulation $O(\log(n))$ is my best guess.